# how do i find the highest value in the list "{ptsvpl-kvm 181} {ptsvpl-esxi 160} {pts24k 38} {pts22k 36} {pts32k 30}"?

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

I have a TCL list which is output of sql query:

CLI:

```
% set res [$dbLab doSQL "SELECT DISTINCT p.platform, a.free FROM(
    SELECT classification, SUM(CASE WHEN is_free = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS free FROM device_availability_pts GROUP BY classification) a
    INNER JOIN profile_platform p ON p.platform = a.classification
    OR p.platform = a.classification ORDER BY free DESC;"]
```

Output:

```
{ptsvpl-kvm 181} {ptsvpl-esxi 160} {pts24k 38} {pts22k 36} {pts32k 30}
```

In this list 160 is the highest number , so i want this list index and its value inside the variable basically want to stor the highest of the list, i tried -stride and other functions of tcl 8.4, but 8.4 is not my version which is use,.

so need some logic whicch will return me `{ptsvpl-esxi 160}` in one variable

Comment: Why isn't the one with `181` the value that you want?

Answer (score 0):

160 is the highest number ?
If as for me the number 181 is the highest number.
see attached my solution (There is certainly a more effective solution)

```
set mlist [list {ptsvpl-kvm 181} {ptsvpl-esxi 160} {pts24k 38} {pts22k 36} {pts32k 30}]
set num {}

foreach el $mlist {
    lappend num [lindex $el 1]
    }

set num_max [join $num ,]
set num_max [expr max($num_max)]

set mysolution [lsearch -inline $mlist *$num_max]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an 8.4 Tcl to test with, but according to [the lsort man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/lsort.htm) this should work:

```
% set result [list {ptsvpl-kvm 181} {ptsvpl-esxi 160} {pts24k 38} {pts22k 36} {pts32k 30}]
% lsort -integer -index end -decreasing $result
{ptsvpl-kvm 181} {ptsvpl-esxi 160} {pts24k 38} {pts22k 36} {pts32k 30}
% lindex [lsort -integer -index end -decreasing $result] 0
ptsvpl-kvm 181
```

and then, if you want to assign those to individual variables:

```
set max [lindex [lsort ...] 0] 
foreach {platform free} $max break
puts $platform
puts $free
```